# wordpress child theme files

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am just starting to work with child themes and think I may possibly be over reaching what child themes are used for.

I am trying to hard code a block into a file in `includes/sections/blog-isotope.php`

which is basically the homepage blog loop.

If I add that file into the same directory but in the child theme folder, nothing happens.

If I update the file in the main theme folder however my changes show (so I know I am dealing with the correct file).

- Is this something I should not be trying to override with my child theme as it is more of a core file than a css file for instance?
- am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: The `includes` folder is not part of [Wordpress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) - so it won't be taken into account in a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: That indicates the parent theme is not loading that file using a "child theme" compatible method. One solution might be to override the function in the parent theme where the file is loaded and use get_stylesheet_directory() for the path instead...